# Is there any way to automatically upload things to Google Photos but NOT Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

I'm using Google's Backup and Sync tool to automatically save photos from my hard drive onto the cloud. The problem is that I want my photos to go into Google Photos  but NOT into Google Drive. In Google Drive they consume my storage quota, and I only want specifically designated documents to be synchronized there.

Is there any way to do this? Even manually deleting the photos from Drive doesn't help because afterwards they are either deleted from my local drive or re-synchronized.

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please consider upvoting it. Reputation points provide an incentive for volunteers to continue answering questions on StackExchange.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is about installable software. There are installable clients form Windows, Mac, Android, iPhone and iPad, so a question like this might be on topic in [su], [apple.se], [android.se] according to the platform corresponding  to the app to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only way to upload photos to Google Photos and not into Drive, is to use the [Google Photos website](https://photos.google.com). On the top right, you can click "upload", then "Computer".

I have not encountered problems when uploading hundreds of photos at a time this way. I agree that it doesn't feel robust for many gigabytes, although most people have fast internet connections. Google should develop a program (like Backup and Sync) that can handle bulk uploads in a robust manner.

Remember to (in Backup and Sync) un-select the folders on your computer that contain your photos, if you don't want to sync them with Drive.